# subprocess.popen( ) executing Python script but not writing to a file

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess, popen

I am trying to run a Python program from inside another Python program using these commands:

1. `subprocess.call(self.runcmd, shell=True)`;
2. `subprocess.Popen(self.runcmd, shell=True)`; and
3. `self.runcmd = " python /home/john/createRecordSet.py /home/john/sampleFeature.dish "`

### Now the script runs fine but the file its supposed to write to is not even getting created, i'm using "w" mode for creating and writing

Comment: What output *are* you getting? Any exceptions, perhaps?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not just `import` the file and use its functionality directly?

Comment: no exceptions it returns 0 for the first command and "<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f7065c99710>" for the second command

Comment: i need to it like this my program is supposed to automate running of python and acl(hpcc) files

Comment: So? How is importing and running directly *not* automating the running? If the problem is that the script you're calling can *only* take command line inputs, **refactor the script**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It sounds like he's running others' scripts. This isn't rocket science, just answer the question he has.

Comment: @CrazyCasta it is *always* worth looking for [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - often, the straightforward solution isn't the best, and exploring how the OP has come to this need can identify a completely different approach. For example, see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267153/3001761, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291080/3001761. *"This isn't rocket science, just answer the question he has"* - please [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and ditch the groundless criticism of others' contributions.

Comment: @CrazyCasta *"my program is supposed to automate running of python and acl(hpcc) files"* did not answer my question. I see no point in continuing this; if you don't like my comments, feel free to flag them as you see fit.

Comment: @tapaskumarMahanta Well, missed that you were using shell=True already. My only guess would be to try getting rid of the spaces at the beginning and end of your string.

Comment: its okay guys i welcome any kind of suggestion or criticism , but here i need to make that subprocess thing work

Comment: Did u try Popen followed by communicate? Also try giving full path of python in self.runcmd.

Comment: i tried this p = subprocess.Popen(self.runcmd, shell=True)
            print p.communicate()[0]                                                               after popen , it returns none, also what do you mean by "full path"

Comment: Absolute path of python.

Comment: proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True; (out, err) = proc.communicate() works for me

Comment: no improvement even after using absolute path , btw i used os.path.abspath to get absolute path

Comment: actually there has been an improvement , now its running the desired python script, but the script in turn was supposed to write to a file , which as of now is not happening , what arguments should i give

Comment: Provide the file name with absolute path.

Comment: @Hema: `.communicate()` returns `None`s unless you use `PIPE`.

Comment: @tapaskumarMahanta: show the code that creates the file. [Create dummy minimal (but complete) code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute path of Python in self.runcmd should do the magic!

Try using the absolute path of file name while opening the file in write mode.